# ¿Como soluciono violacion de segmento ('core' generado) en linux fedora?

Tags: c++, c, linux, debian, fedora

Cuando trato de manejar este mensaje de pedir un texto me aparece este error de violacion de segmento ('core' generado), ¿como lo soluciono? este es mi código:
`

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define __NR_identity 548

long identity_syscall(char* mensaje)
{
    return syscall(__NR_identity, mensaje, sizeof(mensaje) - 1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    long activity;
    char *mensaje;
    printf("Querido Usuario, ingrese el texto que desea escribir al log del kernel:\n");
    fgets(mensaje, 100, stdin);

   activity = identity_syscall(mensaje);

    if(activity < 0)
    {
         perror("Sorry, Jasper. Your system call appears to have failed.");
    }

    else
    {
         printf("Congratulations, Jasper! Your system call is functional. Run the command dmesg in the terminal and find out!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`

Espero que el mensaje que aparezca sea este:
printf("Congratulations, Jasper! Your system call is functional. Run the command dmesg in the terminal and find out!\n");

[Error de violacion de segmento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs3qt.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Ese error significa una cosa: el programa intenta acceder a una región de memoria que no le pertenece.

`mensaje` es un puntero por lo tanto guarda una dirección de memoria, no un mensaje. Además está sin inicializar así que punta a una dirección de memoria desconocida.

Probablemente este sea uno de los causantes. En esta situación tienes dos opciones.

- Convierte el puntero en un arreglo:

  ```
  char mensaje[100];
  ```

  Eso es todo lo que tienes que hacer.
- Reserva memoria con [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) y liberala con [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) en C. En C++ puedes usar [`new[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) y [`delete[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete).

  En C:

  ```
  char* mensaje = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

  ...

  free(mensaje);
  ```

  En C++:

  ```
  char* mensaje = new char[100];

  ...

  delete[] mensaje;
  ```

Por otro lado, `sizeof(mensaje) - 1` te devuelve el tamaño del puntero y por este motivo no es la longitud de la cadena. Sugiero que revises el uso de [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof).

Considera usar [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen):

```
return syscall(__NR_identity, mensaje, strlen(mensaje));
```